# How to change a row in dataframe with values from other dataframe with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I can't find a way to change one row in dataframe with values from other dataframe that are created from csv file.

I want to change a row in Dataframe 1 with the row from Dataframe 2 if the name match (ie England Premier).

If there is a row that exists only in Dataframe 1 I want it to stay as it is.

With df2.update(df1) it overwrites whole Dataframe 1 with rows from DF 2, and if some row that don't exists in df2 then it is deleted.

```
import numpy as numpy
import pandas as pd

nov = 'd:\python\csv_master\lige.csv'
master = 'd:\python\csv_master\master.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(nov, dtype=str)
df2 = pd.read_csv(master, dtype=str)


df1.update(df2)

Dataframe 1
Unnamed: 0                             Naziv Lige   ID Lige Broj tabela Skraceninaziv Tabela tip Slaganje tip Posebno naznaci Sport Stampa Stil Insert pages Broj meceva
0            1                        England Premier     BO2_1           0         EN PL          3            1               0     F      1    2            0          10
1            2                   England Championship   BO2_326           0         EN CH          3            1               0     F      1    2            0          12
2            3                       England League 1   BO2_327           0         EN L1          3            1               0     F      1    2            0          10
3            4                       England League 2   BO2_328           0         EN L2          3            1               0     F      1    2            0          12
4            5                England National League   BO2_329           0         EN NL          3            1               0     F      1    2            0          12


Dataframe 2
Unnamed: 0                             Naziv Lige   ID Lige Broj tabela Skraceninaziv Tabela tip Slaganje tip Posebno naznaci Sport Stampa Stil Insert pages Broj meceva
0            1                        England Premier     BO2_1          16         EN PL          5            3               0     F      1    2            0          10
1            2                   England Championship   BO2_326           8         EN CH          4            2               0     F      1    2            0          12
2            3                       England League 1   BO2_327           4         EN L1          3            1               0     F      1    2            0          10
3            4                       England League 2   BO2_328           4         EN L2          3            1               0     F      1    2            0          12
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I assume the column which you filter by has unique values for every row and there is no ambiguity, you can do it in a loop:

```
for name in df2['c1'].unique():
    mask1 = df1['c1'] == name
    mask2 = df2['c1'] == name
    df1.loc[mask1, :] = df2.loc[mask2, :]
```

so 'c1' is the column you want to check your condition on, the loop iterates through all the unique values of the column in df2 and if the value 
matches the same column in df1, it replaces the row.

I am not sure this is the best way, but it should work. In case there are several conditions which you need to match the rows, just add them to the masks.

Comment: It returns a NaN for those rows existing in DF2.

Comment: @hoppdev you mean rows of df1 which were supposed to be changed are now NaNs?

Comment: Yes. Rows with unique names that are not in DF2 are ok, but those that are overlapping with same name from DF1 and DF2 have NaN for all theirs values after your for loop.

Thank you for your time and input, really appreciated!